# Law on common identities Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, boolean-algebra

I'm studying the theory of algebra and the basic laws. I know the law on common identities

$A+(\bar{A}B)=A+B$

but i wasn't able to demonstrate that :

$\bar{C}+(AB)C=\bar{C}+AB$

this last equation has a similar form of the former equation, but i couldnt succed in demonstrating. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the law of Boolean Algebra you are talking about is the absorption law. Note that $$A+ \overline{A}(B)= A +B $$ $$ \overline{C}+\overline{\overline{C}}(AB)=\overline C + C(AB)= \overline{C}+AB$$

Note that in the second step of our second expression, we have tried to express it like the first one, and noting that $\overline{\overline C}= C$, just compare the forms of the two equations and the result follows.

Comment: The thing i dont understand is the last passage.

Comment: @Poiera Note that $(AB)$ in the second equation takes the role of the $(B)$ in the first. Also, that, $\overline C$ takes the part of $A$ in the first.

Comment: Yes, but i dont understand why (AB) can take the role of (B). Which axiom or theorem allows this ?

Comment: @Poiera Do you understand why (\overline C) can take the role of (A)?

Comment: Yes, but no why (AB) can take the role of (B).. In my post, the latter law is a more complex version of the former. I dont know why that equation lead to that result

Comment: @Poiera Just try to think like this. The role played by the term in the brackets $()$ is same in both the equations. Also, the role played by the first term ($A$ and $\overline C$, respectively) are same.